# Using compile-time logging source generation via extension method

Tags: c#

It really feels like a dumb question, but I don't see my mistake: I want to use [compile-time logging source generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logger-message-generator) and (hopefully ) configured it correctly:

```cs
﻿using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace ScreenshotCreator.Logic;

public static partial class Log
{
    private const string Prefix = nameof(Logic);

    [LoggerMessage(EventId = 0,
                      EventName = Prefix + nameof(PlaywrightInitialized),
                      Level = LogLevel.Information,
                      Message = "Playwright initialized")]
    public static partial void PlaywrightInitialized(ILogger logger);
}
```

Now in my code, I cannot use it as an extension method:

```cs
Log.PlaywrightInitialized(_logger); // compiles and works

_logger.PlaywrightInitialized(); // does not compile
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot `this` before the parameter type `ILogger`

Comment: Oh Jesus, embarrassing - thank you!!! Please provide is as an answer so that you get your merits :)